# Kindle phrases dictionary

Tags: kindle, dictionaries

I recently bought a Kindle Oasis. Since I'm not a native English speaker, I'm using the dictionary option within e-books. I noticed that the default dictionary doesn't recognize pair of words or phrases. So, I tried to search the internet if there is an option to download/purchase a dictionary that includes idioms and phrases but all I could find was dictionaries in e-book format so it can't be used inside other e-books (when marking words). Is there any option to download/purchase a dictionary that includes idioms and phrases that functions as a dictionary (and not as an e-book)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to ebooks-SE.  This is a nice question. Dictionaries are part
of the ebook infrastructure, and unfortunately a much neglected part.